# How to programmatically deploy a C# storm topology to HDInsight

Tags: c#, azure, apache-storm, azure-hdinsight

Is the only way to programmatically submit a storm topology to HDInsight for the package to be a jar file?  It mentions deploying a C# file in the link below but only through a manual process.

If not, how do I deploy a C# topology to an HDInsight cluster programmatically, I.E. without using the UI to submit in Visual Studio.

I've been able to test and work out my storm topology using C# with the submit button but I need this cluster to start every night and stop every morning.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/storm/apache-storm-deploy-monitor-topology-linux

Am I reading `storm jar /usr/hdp/current/storm-client/contrib/storm-starter/storm-starter-topologies-*.jar org.apache.storm.starter.WordCountTopology WordCount` such that **org.apache.storm.starter.WordCountTopology** has to be a jar file?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** The HDInsight tools should be used to submit C# or hybrid topologies to your Storm cluster.

I you want to programmatically deploy a topology, you may refer "[Programmatically deploy a topology to Apache Storm on HDInsight](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/hdinsight-java-deploy-storm-topology/)".

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  This still leaves me with my original questions.  Can you deploy a C# or hybrid topology by calling HDInsight tools programmatically?   Or does any C# topology have to be manually deployed.